# Flutter build_runner command creates duplicate files and folders

Tags: xcode, flutter, build

I am working with a legacy project in flutter thats uses build_runner to generate models for serializing. I use `flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflictbining-outputs` that does the work however it creates all sorts of problems. Namely the duplicate files and folders that mess everything up.

Now it wouldn't be that much of an issue if it only pertains to files, but it at one point it created `.dart_tool` duplicate named `.dart_tool 2`. It always puts 2 at the end of each duplicate. It seemingly at random as some files or folders are duplicated one time but not the other when running the command.
It is a very weird thing I've never seen before and can't find any solution to it. I tried to check the github repo issues of the build_runner package but couldn't find anything like it.
I wonder if anyone have ever stumbled upon this problem.

Biggest problem is that it causes Xcode to completely freeze rendering app totally unusable. It also gets stuck at `flutter clean` when cleaning xCode workspace and just loads indefinitely.

pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.3
  uni_links: ^0.5.1
  firebase_core: "^1.6.0"
  firebase_messaging: ^10.0.7
  firebase_crashlytics: "^2.2.1"
  redux: "^5.0.0"
  redux_logging: "^0.5.0"
  flutter_redux: "^0.8.2"
  shared_preferences: "^2.0.8"
  redux_persist_flutter: "^0.9.0"
  http: "^0.13.3"
  uri: ^1.0.0 
  uuid: "^3.0.3"
  local_auth: "^1.1.8"
  url_launcher: ^6.0.11
  package_info: ^2.0.2
  version: ^2.0.0
  flutter_sticky_header: "^0.6.0"
  trotter: "^1.0.2"
  webview_flutter: "^2.0.14"
  auto_size_text: "^2.1.0"

  built_value: ^8.1.2


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner: ^2.1.2
  built_value_generator: ^8.1.2
```

when running `flutter doctor` it shows no issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is very misleading thread. It was not the command at all. In fact this has happened to many others but not because of build_runner but because of iCloud syncing the files and folders and for some reason it duplicates things.
So i just turned of my iCloud sync and it solved the problem.